# Can't read import password when converting PFX to PEM

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl

I have been trying to convert a .pfx to pem file, without success. I am using SLES15.

I used below command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in input.pfx -out ouput.pem -nodes
```

Then I get :

```
Enter Import Password:
```

I entered the password, then I get:
"Can't read Password"

Comment: Make sure your .pfx file is complete, make sure your -in file is indeed in .pfx format.

Comment: The 100% sure that the file is a .pfx format. How would I make sure that the file is complete.

Comment: The password is long, is it possible that it is unable to read the password because its long?

Comment: I found the solution command is: openssl pkcs12 -in input.pfx -passin file:passwordfile.txt -nocerts -out output.key